# malloc function in C, how can I define a 3D matrix knowin 2 of 3 parameters?

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've tried to create a dynamic matrix 3-D, but when I run my program, it gives me the following worning: "warning: passing argument 1 of ‘malloc’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]".

My code is:

```
//initialization
 char *rndWORD[n_child][100]; 
.........
//create matrix
 for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
      id=rand()%n_child;
      lenght[id][count]= ((rand() % max) + min); 
      rndWORD[id][count] = malloc((lenght+1)); 
  }
```

How can I modify my code?

Comment: Did you include stdlib.h?

Comment: Not what you asked about, but I suspect `(rand() % max) + min` should be more like `(rand() % (max - min)) + min`.

Comment: Given `lenght[id][count]`, `malloc((lenght+1))` is wrong.  If `lenght` (and it should probably be `length`...) is an array of some type, so `lenght + 1` is of type `*lenght`.

Comment: @tstanisl If they hadn't included `<stdlib.h>`, they wouldn't have gotten that particular warning.

Answer (score 0):

The `malloc()` function requires an integer to tell it how many bytes of memory to allocate.  The warning `passing argument 1 of ‘malloc’ makes integer from pointer without a cast` is telling you that instead of passing it an integer, you are actually passing it a pointer.

You haven't shown us how the `lenght` variable is declared, but from the line just above,

```
lenght[id][count] = ...
```

it looks like `lenght` is an array.  (It looks like you're using it to contain multiple lengths, of all the lines you've allocated.)  And when you try to do something with an array, like add 1 to it in `lenght+1`, what you get instead of the whole array is a pointer to its first element.  So that's where the unpexected pointer is coming from that the compiler is complaining about.

It looks like you want

```
rndWORD[id][count] = malloc(lenght[id][count] + 1);
```

Or it might be clearer if you used a temporary variable:

```
int thisLength = (rand() % max) + min; 
lenght[id][count] = thisLength; 
rndWORD[id][count] = malloc((thisLength + 1));
```

Also I suspect you actually want

```
int thisLength = (rand() % (max-min)) + min;
```

if you want random lengths in the range `min`..`max`.